# Powershell compare array to check for GUID

Tags: java, arrays, powershell, windows-installer

I am creating a PowerShell script to check the local system for a predefined list of `GUID` (IdentifyingNumber) which belong to JRE.  The purpose is to remove any old versions that are part of the list before installing the latest version of Java.

The script appears to run correctly for matching the `GUID` but when I run  `msiexec.exe /x` within my for loop and if statement it only runs one time before the script completes.  It should remove each of the old versions that are found.

If anyone could help explain what it is I am missing here it would be greatly appreciated!

```powershell
[string[]] $Java_GUIDS = @(
#Java Auto Updater    
"{4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}",
#Java 8 Update 31 - 64-bit                                                   
"{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418031F0}",
#Java 8 Update 31 - 32-bit                                                              
"{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218031F0}",
#Java 8 Update 25 - 64-bit
"{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}",
#Java 8 Update 20 - 32-bit
"{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218020F0}",
#Java 8 Update 20 - 64-bit
"{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218020FF}",
# ARRAY DEFINITION TRUNCATED
#Java 5 Update 22
"{3248F0A8-6813-11D6-A77B-00B0D0150220}",
#Java 5 Update 23
"{3248F0A8-6813-11D6-A77B-00B0D0150230}")

#Show currently installed Java Version(s)
Write-Host "Currently Installed Java Versions:"
gwmi win32_product -filter "name like 'Java%'" | select name,IdentifyingNumber,Version

[string[]] $Installed = (gwmi win32_product -filter "name like 'Java%'" | Select-Object -expand IdentifyingNumber)

foreach($Installed_GUID in $Installed)
{
    if ($Java_GUIDS -contains $Installed_GUID)
    {
        Write-Host "Found $Installed_GUID in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing..."
        msiexec.exe /x $Installed_GUID /qn /norestart /L*V "C:\Windows\TEMP\Java Removal.log"
        Write-Host "Done"
    }
else
    {
        Write-Host "Did NOT find $Installed_GUID in Java GUIDS Array"
    }
}
Write-Host "Complete"
```

Below are three consecutive runs of the script which show that only one version each run is being uninstalled successfully.

```powershell
PS C:\Users\srj3> C:\Users\srj3\Desktop\Java_Removal.ps1
Currently Installed Java Versions:

name                                                                                    IdentifyingNumber                                                                       Version                                                                                
----                                                                                    -----------------                                                                       -------                                                                                
Java 7 Update 75                                                                        {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F03217075FF}                                                  7.0.750                                                                                
Java 8 Update 31                                                                        {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218031F0}                                                  8.0.310                                                                                
Java 8 Update 25                                                                        {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}                                                  8.0.250                                                                                
Java 7 Update 75 (64-bit)                                                               {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417075FF}                                                  7.0.750                                                                                
Java 8 Update 31 (64-bit)                                                               {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418031F0}                                                  8.0.310                                                                                
Java Auto Updater                                                                       {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}                                                  2.8.31.13                                                                              
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F03217075FF} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218031F0} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417075FF} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418031F0} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Complete



PS C:\Users\srj3> C:\Users\srj3\Desktop\Java_Removal.ps1
Currently Installed Java Versions:

name                                                                                    IdentifyingNumber                                                                       Version                                                                                
----                                                                                    -----------------                                                                       -------                                                                                
Java 8 Update 31                                                                        {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218031F0}                                                  8.0.310                                                                                
Java 8 Update 25                                                                        {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}                                                  8.0.250                                                                                
Java 7 Update 75 (64-bit)                                                               {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417075FF}                                                  7.0.750                                                                                
Java 8 Update 31 (64-bit)                                                               {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418031F0}                                                  8.0.310                                                                                
Java Auto Updater                                                                       {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}                                                  2.8.31.13                                                                              
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218031F0} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417075FF} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418031F0} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Complete



PS C:\Users\srj3> C:\Users\srj3\Desktop\Java_Removal.ps1
Currently Installed Java Versions:

name                                                                                    IdentifyingNumber                                                                       Version                                                                                
----                                                                                    -----------------                                                                       -------                                                                                
Java 8 Update 25                                                                        {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0}                                                  8.0.250                                                                                
Java 7 Update 75 (64-bit)                                                               {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417075FF}                                                  7.0.750                                                                                
Java 8 Update 31 (64-bit)                                                               {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418031F0}                                                  8.0.310                                                                                
Java Auto Updater                                                                       {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}                                                  2.8.31.13                                                                              
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F06417075FF} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418031F0} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Found {4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10} in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing...
Done
Complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling all the msiexec-processes at the same time. Windows Installer/Msiexec only allows one transaction at a time, so you need to wait for each process to finish before starting the next.

```
....
if ($Java_GUIDS -contains $Installed_GUID)
{
    Write-Host "Found $Installed_GUID in Java GUIDS Array.  Removing..."

    #Defining the command here to make it clean. One object per word (split at whitespace).
    $argumentlist = @('/x', $Installed_GUID, '/qn', '/norestart', '/l*v', '"C:\Windows\TEMP\Java Removal.log"')
    Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $argumentlist -Wait

    Write-Host "Done"
}
....
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me the headache.  This solution worked perfectly.